# Variable Arity in C?

Tags: c

Does anyone knows how I might be able to implement variable arity for functions in C?

For example, a summing function:

Sum(1,2,3,4...); (Takes in a variable number of args)

Thanks!

Comment: Variable arity of what? Functions?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you want. Sample code (which need not compile, just demonstrate what you're trying to achieve, and how you'd ideally want it to look) would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Parity, perhaps? In what context? Tell us more.

Comment: Correct, functions. Edited my comment.

Comment: for future reference, "variable arity" functions are normally referred to as "var-args" in C/C++ (possibly as a contraction of "variable arguments" or possibly from the name of the macros used to create such functions, which in turn are such a contraction)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A variable parameter list of ints. Adjust type as necessary:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void myfunc(int firstarg, ...)
{
    va_list v;
    int i = firstarg;

    va_start(v, firstarg);
    while(i != -1)
    {
        // do things
        i = va_arg(v, int);
    }

    va_end(v);
}
```

You must be able to determine when to stop reading the variable args. This is done with a terminator argument (-1 in my example), or by knowing the expected number of args from some other source (for example, by examining a formatting string as in printf).

Answer (score 6):

If all aditional arguments are of the same type, you could also pass an array instead of using variadic macros.

With C99 compound literals and some macro magic, this can look quite nice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define sum(...) \
    sum_(sizeof ((int []){ __VA_ARGS__ }) / sizeof (int), (int []){ __VA_ARGS__ })

int sum_(size_t count, int values[])
{
    int s = 0;
    while(count--) s += values[count];
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%i", sum(1, 2, 3));
}
```

Comment: +1 This is best approach, I use it often. But it will fail if you provide empty argument list. To get around it use following syntax for calculating number of arguments: "sizeof((int[]){0, ##__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int)-1". In case of empty list ##__VA_ARGS__ will eat preceding comma.

Comment: @nubela: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385695/help-me-understand-this-short-chunk-of-code/1386555#1386555

Comment: @qrdl: you'll also have to modify the second expansion of `__VA_ARGS__`, ie replace `(int []){ __VA_ARGS__ }` with `&((int[]){ 0, ##__VA_ARGS__ })[1]` ; most often, I don't bother and accept that it won't work for empty macro invocations...

Comment: this looks perty ugly... i'd have to go with the accepted answer here too

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`va_arg` and friends](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to implement variable arity functions look at http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html for an introduction.