# Help me understand this short chunk of code

Tags: c

I understand this code calculates the sum of the args of a variable, however, I don't understand how it works. It looks really abstract to me. Can someone explain how the below works?

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define sum(...) \
    _sum(sizeof((int []){ __VA_ARGS__ }) / sizeof(int), (int []){ __VA_ARGS__ })

int _sum(size_t count, int values[])
{
    int s = 0;
    while(count--) s += values[count];
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%i", sum(1, 2, 3));
}
```

Comment: the answers so far are not really clear, would someone be kind enough to comment the code and break down the elaboration? thanks!

Comment: @nubela, sorry if my explanation wasn't clear enough. I've added comments to your code which should hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @pax wow thanks! appreciate it! trying to learn C :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the pre-processor macro

```
#define sum(...) \
    _sum(sizeof((int []){ __VA_ARGS__ }) / sizeof(int), (int []){ __VA_ARGS__ })
```

being called with `sum(1,2,3)`, the line is translated (a simple string substitution, replacing `"__VA_ARGS__"` with `"1,2,3"`) into:

```
_sum(sizeof((int []){1,2,3}) / sizeof(int), (int []){1,2,3})
```

which is a function call to `_sum()` passing two things:

- the number of integers in the array {1,2,3} which is 3 (it gets this by dividing the size of the three-integer array by the size of a single integer).
- the pointer to the array itself (or a totally different array containing the same values, depending on how smart your compiler is).

All the `_sum()` function does is add each of the integers to `s` (which is initially zero) until the count runs out.

---

That first bullet point above bears some explanation. When you have an array of `N` elements defined as follows:

```
tType x[22];
```

the size of the *array* is `sizeof(x)`, the size of all elements. The size of a single element of that array is `sizeof(x[0])`, the size of the first element, although I often prefer the `sizeof(*x)` variant.

So, to count the number of elements, you simply divide the total size by the size of an element, using one of the following:

```
sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])
sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x)
```

And, since you've asked for a detailed analysis of the code, here we go:

```
// Needed for printf().

#include <stdio.h>

// Macro to convert sum(n1,n2,...,nN) to _sum(N,n1,n2,...,nN).
// This calculates the length of the array by dividing its size by the size
//   of an int and passes both the length and array through to the new
//   function.
// __VA_ARGS__ is replaced with the entire marcro argument list, '1,2,3' in
//   this case.

#define sum(...) \
    _sum(sizeof((int []){ __VA_ARGS__ }) / sizeof(int), (int []){ __VA_ARGS__ })

// Function to take size and pointer to int array, and return sum.

int _sum (size_t count, int values[]) {
    int s = 0;                // Initial sum of zero.
    while(count--)            // Until elements exhausted (count down).
        s += values[count];   // Add each array element to accumulator.
    return s;                 // Return sum.
}

int main (void) {
    printf ("%i", sum(1, 2, 3));   // Test it with 1, 2 and 3 (should print 6).
}
```

Comment: that's the best description I've ever seen of a variable-length argument list

Comment: Yeah it is. Pax you should write textbooks!

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the expansion of the sample invocation `sum(1, 2, 3)` of the macro

```
#define sum(...) \
    _sum(sizeof((int []){ __VA_ARGS__ }) / sizeof(int), (int []){ __VA_ARGS__ })
```

The `...` mean it's a variadic macro, ie it takes any number of comma-seperated arguments. On expansion, the special preprocessor token `__VA_ARGS__` will be replaced with these arguments, ie

```
(int []){ __VA_ARGS__ }
```

expands to

```
(int []){ 1, 2, 3 }
```

This is a compound literal: C99 allows to create objects with automatic storage duration on-the-fly via such a typed initialization list.

It's important that the size of the array will be inferred: It won't have incomplete type `int []` but will be of type `int [3]`, ie

```
sizeof((int []){ 1, 2, 3 }) = sizeof(int [3]) = 3 * sizeof(int)
```

To get the number of elements, divide by `sizeof(int)`.

The macro invocation `sum(1, 2, 3)` is therefore equivalent to the C90 code

```
int tmp[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
_sum(3, tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code the `sum` macro converts the `sum(1,2,3)` call in main into a call to `_sum` by using `sizeof` to calculate the number of elements `sum` is called with.  The size of an `int` array with three values is going to be `3 * sizeof(int)`, so dividing by `sizeof(int)` yields three again.

Answer (score 0):

Given an integar array, it will sum up all of its elements and return that value.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor here uses variable number of arguments [variadic macro](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/cpp_19.html).
Rest it simply creates an array from argument list and manipulates it