# Can c++11 parameter packs be used outside templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I was wondering if I could have parameter packs consisting of a single, explicitly specified, type. For example, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void show() { }

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void show(First f, Rest... rest)
{
    cout << f << endl;
    show(rest...);
}

void foo(int f, int... args) // error
{
    show(f, args...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(1, 2, 3);
}
```

The problem I'm having is with the definition of `foo()`. With OS X clang++ version 5 (llvm 3.3svn) I get the error `error: type 'int' of function parameter pack does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs`.

Of course, I can get it to compile by changing to `foo()` into a function template:

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo(int f, Args... args)
{
    show(f, args...);
}
```

However now `foo()` will accept `int` for the first parameter, and anything output streamable for the rest. For example:

```
struct x { };
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, x)
{
    o << "x";
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    foo(1, 2, x(), 3); // compiles :(
}
```

Now, I've seen [the accepted solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703826) which suggests using type traits and `std::enable_if`, but that's cumbersome. They also suggested using `std::array` but I think a simple `std::initializer_list` works just fine and looks cleaner, like so:

```
void foo_impl(initializer_list<int> ints)
{
    for(int i: ints)
        cout << i << endl;
}

template<typename... Args>
void foo(int f, Args... args)
{
    foo_impl({f, args...});
}

struct x { };
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, x)
{
    o << "x";
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    foo(1, 2, 3);
    foo(1, 2, x(), 3); // no longer compiles
                       // we also get an error saying no known conversion from 'x' to 'int' :)
}
```

So that's neat. But the question remains, is this necessary? Is there really not a way to define a non-template function which accepts a parameter pack of specific type? Like this:

```
void foo(int... args) { }
```

Comment: No. `int...` doesn't exist. The closest to this is, as you know, is `std::initializer_list<int>`. But I agree that, perhaps, having `int...` rather than `std::initializer_list<int>` could be nice. However, it's difficult to know if this wouldn't create bad side effects that `std::initializer_list<int>` doesn't have.

Comment: @lucas92 the question is tagged c++11, he does not want to use C libraries.

Comment: The reason it must be a template is because each time the function is called with a differnet number of arguments, the compiler must generate the code for a function taking that specific number of arguments.

Comment: Are C++14/C++1y features acceptable?  Because C++14 makes this *easy*.

Comment: @Yakk: Using concept? or `auto`? or both? ;-)

Comment: @Nawaz Concepts lite I'd say.  `template< ConvertsToInt... Ints > void foo(Ints...&& ints)` where `ConvertsToInt` is a type constraint function.  I'd have to poke around with a C++14 compiler to produce a reliable answer, but...  (I'd also have to check that `template<Constraint... Ts>` does not constrains `Ts` to be all the same type -- I remember a discussion about that, forgot what the conclusion was)

Comment: @Yakk: Using concept-lite you could just write this : `void foo(ConvertsToInt ... ints) {}`. No need to write `template<...blah>` stuff. It is so cool :D

Comment: @Yakk: I added it in my answer for just completeness sake.

Comment: The enable_if solution is shorter and clearer than your initializer list with an extra helper function. And it allows more idiomatic looking use in client code. I personally wouldn't call that cumbersome.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
void foo(int... args) {}
```

No you cannot write that.

But you can have the same effect with this approach:

```
template<typename ...Ints>
void foo(Ints... ints) 
{
   int args[] { ints... }; //unpack ints here
   //use args
}
```

With this approach, you can pass all `int` if you want. If any argument passed to `foo` is not `int` or convertible to `int`, the above code will result in compilation error, as it would be the case with `int ...args` approach if it were allowed.

You could also use `static_assert` to ensure all `Ints` are indeed `int` if you want that behaviour:

```
template<typename ...Ints>
void foo(Ints... ints) 
{
   static_assert(is_all_same<int, Ints...>::value, "Arguments must be int.");

   int args[] { ints... }; //unpack ints here
   //use args
}
```

Now you've to implement `is_all_same` meta-function which is not difficult to implement.

Alright, this is the basic idea. You can write more sophisticated code with variadic templates and with the help of some utility meta-functions and helper functions.

For lots of work that you can do with variadic arguments, you don't even need to store in `args[]` array, e.g if you want to print the arguments to `std::ostream`, then you could just do it as:

```
struct sink { template<typename ...T> sink(T && ... ) {} };

template<typename ...Ints>
void foo(Ints... ints) 
{
    //some code

     sink { (std::cout << ints)... };
}
```

Here you create a temporary object of type `sink` so that you use unpack the template arguments using list-initialization syntax.

Last you could just use `std::initializer_list<int>` itself:

```
void foo(initializer_list<int> const & ints) 
{

}
```

Or `std::vector<int>` in case if you need vector-like behavior inside `foo()`. If you use any of these, you have to use `{}` when calling the function as:

```
f({1,2,3});
```

That may not be ideal but I think with the advent of C++11 you will see such code very frequently!

Comment: I would also point out, for the sake of argument, that you could use `is_all_same` in an SFINAE fashion to remove `foo` from the overload set when the condition is not matched, instead of having it eagerly "capture" all calls just to fail.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: That may be good or bad, depending on what you want to do. An advantage with `static_assert` is that you can print good error messages. Of course, this doesn't fit if you want to other overloaded to be selected in case this `foo` isn't intended, in which case SFINAE would help.

Comment: Your `Integer` may be not quite right: `f( 'a', 0x0l )` would work with a function `f( int, int )`, but would fail with your `f( Integer... ints )`.  Hence, `f( ConvertsToInteger...&& ints )` where you `return std::is_convertible< T, int >::value;` rather than `is_same`.  This emulates normal function resolution "convert 1 step" in the call that `template` functions do not do.

Comment: @Yakk: It all depends on how you define `Integer` of course. In this case, I show how to restraint it to only `int`. If you want to include `char` also, then you've to write the concept accordingly, but I think once you know the basic, you can write those variations yourself.

Comment: @Yakk: Added another concept called `Integral` which captures all integral types only, excluding the floating points.

Comment: @Nawaz I would aim for "anything that would work if your arguments where actually `int...`", which would be anything convertible-to-`int` implicitly.  It isn't quite perfect, because your overload will be overly "greedy", but...

Comment: @Yakk: Actually you cannot say `int` should work for `double` also, because there might be another overloaded function accepting only `double`. So it is up to the OP how he/she defines the concept depending on how he/she wants it to work. I cannot capture what he/she eventually needs, so I only demonstrated the basic idea, not a production-level code.

Comment: int... and Ints... are same only if you you pass to function real integers, but what about implicit conversions? And I am not talking about classes that can be constructed like this {1, "str"}.

Answer (score 8):

As with Brian's answer, I realize this was originally intended for C++11, but in C++20 this can be solved in a very simple way using concepts:

```
#include <concepts>

void f(std::integral auto... ints)
{
    // ...
}
```

`std::integral` accepts any integral type, so it's a bit more general, if that is acceptable. If not, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <concepts>

template<class T>
concept exactly_int = std::same_as<int,T>;

void f(exactly_int auto... ints)
{
   // ...
}
```

To add a bit more explanation to this, the `auto` is essentially an implicit template, and the name before it is constraining what types are allowed. So in the first example, anything that satisfies `std::integral` (`int`,`long`,`unsigned`,`char`, etc.) will be allowed. The second allows only `int`s, since that is the only type that satisfies the concept that was defined.

There is an even simpler way to do this: Concepts when used as constrains use the type that is being constrained as its first argument, so you can simply write:

```
#include <concepts>

void f(std::same_as<int> auto... ints)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: This is a great workaround. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Why the `foo_impl` workaround, and not just use `initialize_list<int>` in `foo`'s signature directly?  It clarifies that you accept a variable-size argument list of said type.

Comment: Because that would require `foo({1, 2, 3})` and the intent was to support the interface `foo(1, 2, 3)`. However, I suppose you could just rename `foo_impl()` to `foo()` to support both call styles at the same time, which might be best anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You might specify the type you want to show:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void show_type() {}

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
void show_type(const T& x, Rest... rest)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    show_type<T>(rest...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void foo(int x, Args... args)
{
    show_type<int>(x, args...);
}

struct X { };
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, X)
{
    o << "x";
    return o;
}


int main()
{
    foo(1, 2, 3);
    foo(1, 2, 3.0); // Implicit conversion
    // or just
    show_type<int>(1, 2, 3);
    foo(1, 2, X()); // Fails to compile
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is tagged C++11, but the features of C++17/1z works fantastically here so I figured its solution is worth posting:

```
template<typename... Ints>
void foo(Ints... xs)
{
    static_assert(std::conjunction<std::is_integral<Ints>...>::value);
    (std::cout << xs << '\n', ...);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a template like

```
<MyType i, MyType ... myTypes>
```

for function, but you cat use it for class/struct.
Just change your function to a static struct member and it's done (sum example):

```
 template<int i, int ... ints>
 struct A <i, ints...> {
    static int Do() {
        return i + A<ints...>::Do();
    }
 };
```

This is not all job to do - a boundary struct is also needed. All the example (with Show() method):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<int ...> // declaration needed
struct A {};

template<int i>   // boundary
struct A <i>{
    static void Show() {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
};

template<int i, int ... ints> // main struct
struct A <i, ints...> {
    static void Show() {
        cout << i << endl;
        A<ints...>::Show();
    }
};

int main() {
    A<5, 45, 2, -100>::Show();
    cout << endl;
    A<-15, -3, 2>::Show();
    return 0;
}
```