# Can we use parameter packs as std::vector initializers?

Tags: c++11, stdvector, variadic-templates

I'm experimenting with C++11 (I've used old C++ so far) and I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

constexpr bool all_true(){
    return true;
}

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
constexpr bool all_true(Head head, Tail... tail){
    static_assert( is_convertible<bool, Head>::value, "all_true arguments must be convertible to bool!");
    return static_cast<bool>(head) && all_true(tail...);
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print_as(Args... args){
    static_assert( all_true(is_convertible<T,Args>::value...), "all arguments must be convertible to the specified type!");
    vector<T> v {static_cast<T>(args)...};
    for(T i : v) cout << i << endl;
}

int main(){
    print_as<bool>(1, 2, 0, 4.1);
}
```

The code compiles and runs as expected (I used gcc 4.6). I would like to aks the following questions:

1. I initialized a std::vector with an expanded parameter pack ( vector v {static_cast(args)...}; ). Is this correct C++11? I haven't found this feature explained anywhere.
2. I don't like too much the declaration of all_true because I know the type but I use templates. Is it possible to use something similar to the following?

   ```
   constexpr bool all_true(bool head, bool... tail){...} // This code doesn't compile
   ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible to use pack expansions inside initialiser lists. C++11 [temp.variadic]§4 allows this:

   > ... Pack expansions can occur in the following contexts:
   >   ...
   >
   > - In an *initializer-list* (8.5); the pattern is an *initializer-clause.*
2. No, there's no way to make a non-template typesafe variadic function. What you have is OK. There was a [question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20407753/1782465) recently.

Comment: 1) Thanks, I didn't think about looking directly into the standard specification...
2) I think it would be a nice addition to the standard if parameter packs with specified type would be available. Let's hope for a future addition!