# variadic templated overload of operator [] in templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, variadic-templates, subscript-operator

I am trying to overload the operator[]. The following code does not compile and I suspect I'm just making a syntax mistake, but I need help understanding what I'm doing wrong and why.

Here is an excerpt of the relevant code:

```
template <typename T>
class MultiDimArray{
public:
  template <typename ...I>
  T& operator[](const size_t firstIndex,const size_t ...I);
  //...
}

template <typename T> //class's template parameter(s)
template <typename ...I> //function's template parameter(s)
T& MultiDimArray<T>::operator[](const size_t firstIndex,const size_t ...I){
  //...
}
```

Note1: I'm trying to follow the compile time convertible to type checking suggested at the top of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20407859/1598298).

Comment: Also see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator[]` can only take one argument, the easiest solution is to overload `operator()` instead and access members via `()` instead of `[]`.

The proper syntax would then be:

```
    template <class T>
    template <class ... I>
    T& MultiDimArray<T>::operator()(I ... i)
    {
    }
```

You were also using the types list `I` as though they were parameter names instead of type names (which is fixed in my example).