# How to check if a type is instantiated from a certain variadic template class in a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

Let's say I have:

```
template <typename...>
class Foo { };
```

Then I define another function:

```
template <typename... T>
void Bar(const T&... arguments) { }
```

How do I check if all `T`s passed to `Bar` are all instantiated from `Foo`? Like:

```
Foo<int> a;
Foo<int, int> b;
Bar(a, b); // OK
int c;
Bar(a, b, c); // ill-formed
```

I want a way to detect ill-formed arguments like `Bar(a, b, c);` Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20407859/13188071) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trait to test for instantiations of `Foo`, and then fold it across all your parameters.

```
template <typename>
struct is_foo : std::false_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct is_foo<Foo<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_foo_v = is_foo<T>::value;

template <typename... T>
void Bar(const T&... arguments) {
    static_assert((is_foo_v<T> && ...), "arguments must all be Foos");
}
```

[See it on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0efbda5d33072888)

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, if `T` is `Foo<int>`, the `constexpr bool` evaluates to `constexpr bool is_foo_v = is_foo<Foo<int>>::value;`, then does the compiler chooses the second `is_foo` since it's kind of "more valid"? Also, I don't think the second `is_foo` needs to be a variadic template struct or am I missing something?

Comment: The specialisation matches all `Foo` instantiations, and nothing else. It copies the template parameters of `Foo`

Comment: When `T` is `Foo<int>`, does the second `is_foo` evaluates to `struct is_foo<Foo<Foo<int>>>` or `struct is_foo<Foo<int>>`?

Comment: @palapapa look at [Partial Specialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization), When `is_foo<Foo<int>>` is compiled, the specialisation that inherits `true_type` is matched, with `Ts...` equal to `int`

Comment: Why is the second `is_foo` a variadic template though? Even if I write something like `is_foo_v<Foo<int, int>>`, the `T` is `Foo<int, int>` which is still a single type. Is this because that the specialization will only take the `int, int` part of `Foo<int, int>` so it needs to be variadic?

Comment: Yes, the `Ts...` is to match `int, int` in `Foo<int, int>` etc, There is no `T` in the `is_foo` template. There is an un-named template parameter in the primary template, and the partial specialisation matches any instantiation of `Foo` there

Comment: You could have a further specialisation, e.g. for `Foo` with at least one `int` parameter `template <typename... Ts, typename... Us> struct is_foo<Ts..., int, Us...> /* something*/`