# Handling variadic function arguments of type 'std::size_t'

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, c++20, variadic-functions

I am trying to get the hang of variadic function/template parameters. However, in the two functions below, I am very confused as to why `SumIndices` does not compile (I get the compiler error "expansion pattern ‘std::size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} contains no parameter packs") while `SumValues` does.

```
template <typename ...t_data_type>
constexpr auto SumValues(t_data_type ..._values) { 
  return (_values + ...); 
}

constexpr auto SumIndices(std::size_t ..._indices) { 
  return (_indices + ...); 
}
```

I would much appreciate it if anyone can clarify this confusion for me!

Comment: You cannot use parameters packs without templates. Your attempted overload for `size_t` is not valid syntax. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407753/can-c11-parameter-packs-be-used-outside-templates).

Comment: @Mansoor Ok, so what is the appropriate way to templatise `SumIndices` if it is to only accept arguments of type `size_t`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by templatise, your overload is unnecessary, you can remove it and not lose any functionality. If you call the first variadic function with `size_t` arguments, it will work.

Comment: @Mansoor Oh ok, I see. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Mansoor So just to give you some context, if I were to write a subscript operator overload in a multi-dimensional array class, e.g. to access the (i, j, k, ...) entry of an l x m x n x ... array, would I still use `typename` in the template argument and not explicitly require that the indices be of type `size_t`?

Comment: Yes, if I have understood your problem correctly. If you want do type checking, you can do this with SINFAE, Concepts (C++20) or `static_assert` inside the function.

Comment: @Mansoor Okay, great. Thanks again for the insights! :)

Comment: `constexpr auto SumIndices(std::initializer_list<std::size_t> ns) { return std::accumulate(ns.begin(), ns.end(), std::size_t{}); }` might be an option, just call it with extra `{..}` at call site: `SumIndices({4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42}) == 108`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the idea. Although I'm specifically looking to implement so that I would not require additional `{}` braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first case you have [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).
In second case, you have [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) from C.

Variadic templates allow you to type-safely pass different types into your function.
Example of print with this:

```cpp
// Create this function to terminate argument depended lookup
void PrintValues(std::ostream&){}
template<typename TFirstArg, typename ...TArgs>
void PrintValues(std::ostream& output, const TFirstArg& arg, const TArgs... other_args){
   // Recursive call to another function which has N-1 args
   // If other_args are empty, it would call `void PrintValues(std::ostream&)`
   // If they are non empty, it would call another instantiation of this template
   PrintValues(output << arg, other_args...);
}
```

And this can be called this way:

```cpp
PrintValues(std::cout, 5LL, 7.59, "Hello world", std::string{"bingo"});
```

With varargs you can do this:

```cpp
void PrintFewNumbers(size_t number_of_args, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, number_of_args);
    for (size_t idx_of_arg, idx_of_arg < number_of_args; ++idx_of_arg){
        size_t current_arg = va_arg(args, size_t);
        std::cout << current_arg;
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

And you can call it using this:

```cpp
PrintFewNumbers(0);
PrintFewNumbers(5, 1,2,3,4,5);
```

You should prefer variadic templates to variadic args because they are type safe. However, they are not always usable.

Answer (score 4):

With C++20, you can create your `SumIndices` easily with the [Concept library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts):

```
#include <concepts>
auto SumIndices(std::same_as<std::size_t> auto ... indices);
```

However, do note that this have a strict rule on only data of **`std::size_t`** or **equivalent** types can be passed to the function.

Instead, you might consider to use `std::integral` or `std::unsigned_integral`, which would allow other integral types to be used:

```
auto SumIndices(std::integral auto ... indices);
```

Comment: That's very neat! Thanks for this tip :)

Comment: I prefer to use `auto SumIndices(std::convertible_to<std::size_t> auto... indices);`

Comment: @康桓瑋 Would you mind elaborating on why `std::convertible_to<std::size_t>` would be preferable to the alternatives in the above answer?

Comment: @niran90. Because it can accept `std::integral_constant<int, 0>{}`, and intuitively express the expected type (`std::size_t`) type to be accepted by the function.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Note that that takes by value.  So if some user-defined type has an `operator size_t()const` it will be *copied*, then called each time in the function you convert it to a `size_t`.