# How to specialize template pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I have the following code, which tries to convert a binary number (passed as a list of booleans, least-significant first, variable lenght) into a decimal number:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int bin_to_dec(int multi, T first) {
    cout<<"mutli"<<multi<<endl;
  return first?multi:0;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
int bin_to_dec(int multi, T first, Args... args) {
    cout<<"mutli"<<multi<<endl;
  return (first?multi:0) + adder(multi*2, args...);
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
int bin_to_dec(T first, Args... args) {
    cout<<"mutli"<<1<<endl;
  return (first?1:0) + adder(2, args...);
}

int main()
{
    cout<<bin_to_dec(true, true, false, true)<<endl;
}
```

It works quite well, but I would like to make it possible only for booleans, so when I try something like bin_to_dec(1,2,3) it should not compile. I was trying to use something like

```
template<bool First, bool... Bools>
```

but I can't figure out how to go further with that. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703658/specifying-one-type-for-all-arguments-passed-to-variadic-function-or-variadic-te)

Answer (score 2):

The obvious approach is to remove the function from the overload set for all template arguments but `bool`:

```
template <typename... T>
std::enable_if_t<variadic_and(std::is_same<T, bool>::value...), int>
bin_to_dec(T... bits) {
    // probably delegate to differently named functions as an implementation detail
    // ...
}
```

`variadic_and()` would be a `constexpr` function returning `true` if all its arguments are `true`:

```
constexpr bool variadic_and() { return true; }
template <typename... T>
constexpr bool variadic_and(bool v, T... vs) {
    return v && variadic_and(vs...);
}
```

With C++17 `variadic_and()` would be necessary as parameter packs can be expanded with an operator. For example, the implementation of `variadic_and()` could look like this:

```
template <typename... T>
constexpr bool variadic_and(T... vs) { return (vs && ...); }
```

The same approach could be used directly within `std::enable_if_t<...>`.

**Note**: the approaches used above requires that the arguments are deduced as `bool`, i.e., they pretty much need to be of type `bool`. Since the function shouldn't be callable with `int` parameters and these would convert to `bool`, testing whether the argument type is convertable to `bool` doesn't seem appropriate. However, it *may* be reasonable to allow some conversions. If so, a corresponding trait would be used in the first paramter to `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: `std::enable_if_t <`[`std::conjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction)`< std::is_same<T, bool>...>{}, int>`for c++17

Answer (score 1):

Just use a static assert. This works perfectly well:

```
int bin_to_dec() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
int bin_to_dec(T first, Args ... rest)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<bool, T>::value, "Only valid for bools");
    return (first ? 1 : 0) + (bin_to_dec(rest...) << 1);
}

int main()
{
    cout<<bin_to_dec(true, true, false, true)<<endl;
    cout<<bin_to_dec(1, 2, 3)<<endl;  //compile error
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the downvote. The above code works exactly as the OP has asked, which is to give the right answer with `bool`s and to fail to compile with anything else. I don't see how the comment above is relevant as the OP never asked for a way to remove a function from the overload set