# For every template type an argument of a set type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor, variadic-templates

Say I have a variadic template class. How do I create a function such that it's arguments are of a set type, for example `int`, with the number of arguments being equal to the number of template types?

```
template <typename... Types>
class Test
{
public:
    void Func(???); // I don't know how to declare such a function
}

Test<string, bool, long> myTest; // Three types
myTest.Func(905, 36, 123315); // Three arguments, but always of type int.
```

In the end, the goal of the function is to return a tuple of the provided ints. For simplicity I showed the function to be void in the example code.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703658/specifying-one-type-for-all-arguments-passed-to-variadic-function-or-variadic-te) with additional `sizeof...`check?

Comment: Like this? http://ideone.com/PASclP

Comment: You don't even need `Types` here since the parameter pack size can be deduced by the call : http://ideone.com/tPe6Tj

Comment: @Simon Kraemer I want Func to have a number of arguments equal to the number of class template types. In addition I want to force them to always be an integer.

Comment: @Gill Bates That is getting pretty close. Next up for me: How to have a return type std::tuple<> containing a number of ints equal to the number of types?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
template <typename... Types>
class Test
{
    template <typename>
    using int_t = int;

public:    
    void Func(int_t<Types>... ints)
    {
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d148b8d550cb28b)

Comment: Clever! I like this solution.

Comment: Note that your solution allows implicit conversions - not sure if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on how this works? I have never seen a template and using combined.

Comment: @AartStuurman it's an alias template, designed in a way such that whatever you specify as a type template argument, say `T`, then `int_t<T>` will always be replaced by `int`. The unused type template parameter is there to exploit pack expansion and generate a function parameter list

Answer (score 4):

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DVTmcGiqgm54yodp) - *(works with C++11)*

---

If you do not require SFINAE, you can use `static_assert` to make sure your conditions are met:

```
template <typename... Types>
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    void Func(Ts...)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(Types), "");
        static_assert(std::conjunction<std::is_same<Ts, int>...>{}, "");
    }
};
```

*(If you need SFINAE, use `std::enable_if`.)*

[`std::conjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) checks that all the conditions passed to it are true.

---

With the above example, the following calls are valid/invalid:

```
myTest.Func(905, 36, 123315); // valid
myTest.Func(905, 36, 123315.f); // invalid
myTest.Func(905, 22); // invalid
```

As you can see, *implicit conversions* are not allowed with this solution. You could use [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) instead of `std::is_same` if you want them to be allowed.

Comment: Plus `conjunction` is C++17, risky risky.

Comment: @GillBates: it's easy to implement it, see my wandbox example. It works in C++11.

Comment: I agree that your solution fully solves my question. However, Piotr Skotnicki's solution seems easier to read in my opinion, and was(for me) easier to expand to other similar uses. As such I choose his answer as the best, even though yours helped me a lot too.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree, Piotr's solution is definitely better :)