# Variadic class template

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem compiling this code.

All I am trying to do is create a variadic class template that can give me the sum of all elements that are passed in (eg. 1,2,3,4,5,6 should give 21) whether it's `int` or `float`. I could basically do it with two function templates recursively for which I'm getting the answer correctly but when I'm implementing it in class it doesn't give me an answer.

```
template <typename T>
class Myclass
{
public:

    T sum;

    T func(T A,T... B)
    {
        sum+=A;
        func(B...);
    }

    T func(T A)
    {
        sum+=A;
        return sum;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Myclass<int> myclass;
    cout<<myclass.func(12,11,11,23);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your first method doesn't return a `T`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code [does not compile](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tM3x4V0OiRBqgYNB) because `T...` is an invalid variadic expansion, as `T` is not a parameter pack.

You code has also several other issues. I will address them in the snippet below:

```
template <typename T>
class Myclass
{
public:
    // `sum` needs to be initialized to a value, otherwise its value
    // will be undefined.
    T sum = 0;

    // `TRest...` is a template variadic type pack.
    template <typename... TRest>
    T func(T A, TRest... B)
    {
        sum+=A;

        // You need to return from the recursive case of `func`.
        return func(B...);
    }

    T func(T A)
    {
        sum+=A;
        return sum;
    }
};
```

[**working wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iS81LEu7pXkdDlp4)

---

Note that the values matched in `TRest...` can be of any type. If you want  to force them to be `T`, you can use the following technique *(or `static_assert`)*:

```
template <typename...>
using force_to_t = T;

// ...

T func(T A, force_to_t<TRest>... B)
{
    sum+=A;

    // You need to return from the recursive case of `func`.
    return func(B...);
}
```

*I learned this solution thanks [to Piotr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40015608/598696) on another question.*

Comment: Calling func more than once is still problematic though, e.g. add another cout<<myclass.func(12,11,11,23); to that example

Comment: That `force_to_t` is a great trick! TIL something new (and very useful!).

Answer (score 3):

```
T func(T A,T... B)
{
    sum+=A;
    func(B...);

}
```

This is not valid C++ syntax when `func` is not a function template with `T` its template parameter pack. `...` can only be used to expand packs; `T` is a non-pack template parameter of the class template.

There are two ways to do this, depending on what you want to achieve.

One: If you want `func` to accept a mix of arbitrary types, you can make it a (member) function template:

```
template <typename T>
class Myclass
{

public:

    T sum;

    template <class F1, class... F>
    T func(F1 A, F... B)
    {
        sum+=A;
        func(B...);
        return sum;
    }

    template <class F>
    T func(F A)
    {
        sum+=A;
        return sum;
    }

};
```

Two: If you want `func` to only accept `T`s, you can change it to use an initializer list:

```
template <typename T>
class Myclass
{

public:

    T sum;

    T func(std::initializer_list<T> A)
    {
        for (const auto& a : A)
            sum+=a;
        return sum;
    }

};
```

Note that this will require calling it with a list in braces (e.g. `func({1, 2, 42})` instead of `func(1, 2, 42)`, but it's the approach also taken by e.g. [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max).

---

Notice that there are a few issues in your code unrelated to the question at hand.

One, which I fixed in the example above, is that your first overload of `func` didn't return anything. Calling it would result in Undefined Behaviour.

Another one, pointed out by [@Zereges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3087601/zereges) in the comments, is that `T sum` is not initialised explicitly. If `MyClass` is instantiated with a POD type (such as `int` or `double`), it will be used uninitialised. You should add a constructor for `Myclass`:

```
Myclass() : sum{} {}
```

Comment: There is second problem with the code, `T sum;` is declaration and if T is POD type, it won't be properly initialized.

Comment: @Zereges Yes indeed. Maybe the real code contains a ctor which was omitted from question?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the need for recursive calls by writing the sequential `sum+=A` as an initialiser for a `std::initializer_list`:

```
template <typename T>
class Myclass
{
    template <class... F>
    T func_impl(F... A)
    {
        std::initializer_list<int>{
            ((void)(sum+=A), 0)...};
        return sum;
    }
public:
    Myclass() :sum(){}
    T sum;
    template <class F1, class... F>
    T func(F1 A, F... B)
    {
        return func_impl(A, B...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with another approach that avoid recursive call.

```
template <typename T>
class Myclass
{
public:
    T sum;

    Myclass() { sum = 0; }

    template<typename ...T1>
    T func(T1 ... args)
    {
        auto l_expansion_list =
        {
            (
                [this, &args]()
                {
                    this->sum += args;
                    return true;
                }()
            )...
        };

        return sum;
    }
};
```