# How to use Variadic Function with strings, without using templates?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I have the following template function:

```
struct ms {
    template <typename... Args>
    void update(string& query, Args&... args);
};

template <typename... Args>
void ms::update(string& query, Args&... args)
{
    const int size = sizeof...(args);
    vector<string> vec = { args... };
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << query << ": " << vec[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

However, I would like to eliminate the use of template and simply make this a member function that takes one or more string arguments. All of the documentation and examples on Variadic Functions I can find show use of character arrays and doing a while pointer != null to grab each value in the array.

If I do something like:

```
void update(string& query, string&... args);
```

how would I iterate over the args parameters, if there are any?

Comment: Why not just pass a container of strings, e.g. `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Take a `vector<std::string>` directly ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703658/specifying-one-type-for-all-arguments-passed-to-variadic-function-or-variadic-te

Comment: What's wrong with the templated version actually? Well, you could use an ellipsis and `va_args` and that stuff, but I wouldn't really recommend that.

Comment: If you don't need to take ownership of the strings, initializer_list is actually a much better solution than a vector of strings.

Comment: @user0042 we were instructed to minimize use of templates where possible due to overhead. @ others, the input parameters are stored in an array of structures which contain a multidimensional character array. Due to the way I've overloaded some operators, its simpler to call a function like: update(query, arg[column][row], arg[colum2][row]...) etc. If I were to do it by passing in a vector directly, then I would have to first create a vector out of all of these strings, then pass the vector which would ultimately be less efficient (or at least less clean).

Comment: @user1324674 What _overhead_ are you talking about?

Comment: @user0042 code size? I don't know the difference between using a template vs variadic, though. Are they the same?

Comment: @user1324674 OK, if code size really is a critical path for you, then go with the good old ellipsis and [`va_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg).

Comment: You can use initializer list `void update( std::initializer_list<std::string> args)`

Comment: No, do not use va_arg. Use vector, use initializer list, use templates, but not va_arg. It's a pile of hot type unsafe garage.

Comment: You can either use the templated variadic fucntion or old plain 'c' style variadic function with va_args. But in the latter case there is no info about neither parameter type nor about the number of parameters, unless you specifically provide them (as a format string in printf). The other method is to overload the function with all possible number of parameters (if you know it).

Answer (score 1):

This is an `array_view<T>`:

```
template<class T>
struct array_view;
template<class D>
struct array_view_base;

template<class T>
struct array_view_base<array_view<T>> {
  T* b=0; T* e=0;
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return e; }
  T& operator[](std::size_t i)const{ return begin()[i]; }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  T& front() const { return *begin(); }
  T& back() const { return *(end()-1); }
  array_view<T> without_front( std::size_t N=1 ) const {
    N=(std::min)(N, size());
    return {begin()+N, end()};
  }
  array_view<T> without_back( std::size_t N=1 ) const {
    N=(std::min)(N, size());
    return {begin(), end()-N};
  }

  array_view_base( T* s, T* f ):b(s),e(f){}
  array_view_base( T* s, std::size_t sz ):array_view_base(s, s+sz) {}

  template<std::size_t N>
  array_view_base( T(&arr)[N] ):array_view_base(arr, N) {}
  template<class C,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<C>, array_view<T>>{}, int> =0
  >
  array_view_base( C&& c ):array_view_base(c.data(), c.size()) {}
};

template<class T>
struct array_view:array_view_base<array_view<T>> {
  using array_view_base<array_view<T>>::array_view_base;
};
template<class T>
struct array_view<T const>:array_view_base<array_view<T const>> {
  using array_view_base<array_view<T const>>::array_view_base;
  array_view( std::initializer_list<T> il ):array_view( std::addressof(*il.begin()), il.size() ) {}
};
```

it works a bit like a `gsl::span<T>`.  it is a contiguous range of `T`.

Unlike `gsl::span<T>`, `array_view<T const>` can be constructed from an `initializer_list<T>`.

With it your code should look like:

```
struct ms {
  void update(string const& query, array_view<string const> args);
};
void ms::update(string const& query, array_view<string const> args)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i) {
    cout << query << ": " << args[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

and you call it like:

```
ms{}.update( "Hello", {"one", "two", "three"} );
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c04530463006320).

---

As a worse example, simply take a `std::vector<std::string>`.

At point of call

```
ms{}.update( "Hello", {"one", "two", "three"} );
```

also works.  Unlike my solution, this causes a memory allocation.