# C++ Getting a number of elements in variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

So I'm trying to get a number of elements in my variadic template like so:

```
Test(const T& t...);

template<typename T>
inline Class<T>::Test(const T& t...){
     int num = sizeof...(t);
     ...
}
```

However it doesn't compile and I get the following errors:

> error C3523: 'sizeof...' requires as its argument an unexpanded parameter pack
>
> 't' is not a valid operand for 'sizeof...'. Did you mean to use
> 'sizeof'?

What is the correct way to get the number of arguments in `t...`?

Comment: `template<typename T>` Is not a variadic template. `template<typename... T>` is.

Comment: Your template have only one parameter T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `T` were a parameter pack, you could use the following syntax to declare a function that takes a sequence of parameters with types corresponding to those in the parameter pack:

```
inline Class<T>::Test(const T&... t) { /* ... */ }
```

However, it appears that `T` isn't a parameter pack. It's just a single type parameter. Plus, you put the `...` in the wrong place. So what you really did was declare a function that takes a single parameter of type `T`, plus a C-style ellipsis. (Yes, the comma before the ellipsis is optional!)

So when you write `sizeof...(t)`, the compiler complains because `t` is not a pack. It's just a normal parameter.

Perhaps you wanted to declare `Test` to be a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments, but all of type `const T&`? Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do that in current C++. See [Specifying one type for all arguments passed to variadic function or variadic template function w/out using array, vector, structs, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703658/specifying-one-type-for-all-arguments-passed-to-variadic-function-or-variadic-te) for solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Try `std::tuple` metaprogramming: `std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Types...>>::value` yields the number of type parameters. For example, this code prints `4`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename ...Types>
constexpr std::size_t Test(Types&& ... args){
    constexpr std::size_t sz = std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Types...>>::value;
    return sz;
}

int main()
{
    std::size_t val = Test(0, 0L, 'a', std::cin);
    std::cout << val;
}
```