# C++11 variable number of arguments, same specific type

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic

Question is simple, how would I implement a function taking a variable number of arguments (alike the variadic template), however where all arguments have the same type, say int.

I was thinking about something alike this;

```
void func(int... Arguments)
```

Alternatively wont a recursive static assert on the types work?

Comment: If you need a variable number of int arguments, why not pass a vector to it? What will these arguments do?

Comment: Oh >.<, I really just could do that. And I'm just playing around with variadic templates.

Comment: Don't use "...". The ellipsis is a dangerous carryover from C. Use higher-level C++ constructs and libraries instead. ("C++ Coding Standards", Sutter/Alexandrescu)

Comment: @DanielDaranas, OP is referring to parameter packs, not the C-style varargs ellipsis.

Comment: @dhavenith Ah, yes. I get it now.

Comment: @Shark: 1. So as not to use the stack. 2. So as not to depend on `<vector>` 3. To be more flexible. 4. To be less flexible, i.e. not have someone pass a zillion elements in a vector. 5. To be constexpr.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable number of parameters in function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579719/variable-number-of-parameters-in-function-in-c)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A possible solution is to make the parameter type a container that can be initialized by a brace initializer list, such as [`std::initializer_list<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) or [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). [For example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=85f64e5da275077e0b513776c2a85733-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

void func(std::initializer_list<int> a_args)
{
    for (auto i: a_args) std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    func({4, 7});
    func({4, 7, 12, 14});
}
```

Comment: Say the numbers aren't constants will this approach still work?

Comment: Thats great but the number of arguments here is known at runtime only. initializer_list lacks a constexpr version. I would need that :(

Comment: This works as long as the function doesnt take variable number of references. `std::initializer_list<int&>` doesn't work

Comment: There is a design flaw with std::initialiser_list in that it's not move-aware. For this reason, when passing large or non-copyable types you should prefer Jonathan Wakely's solution (below) that allows perfect forwarding.

Comment: this passes those values `{4,7}` by value right? even if they were named int variables?

Comment: @hmjd: And will this take anything and cast it intoan initializer list? e.g. a tuple, a vector, anything?

Answer (score 21):

Here's a version that removes the function from the overload set, instead of giving a static_assert. This is allows you to provide other overloads of the function that could be used when the types aren't all the same, rather than a fatal static_assert that can't be avoided.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... T>
  struct all_same : std::false_type { };

template<>
  struct all_same<> : std::true_type { };

template<typename T>
  struct all_same<T> : std::true_type { };

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
  struct all_same<T, T, Ts...> : all_same<T, Ts...> { };

template<typename... T>
typename std::enable_if<all_same<T...>::value, void>::type
func(T...)
{ }
```

If you want to support perfect forwarding you probably want to decay the types before checking them, so that the function will accept a mix of lvalue and rvalue arguments as long as they have the same type:

```
template<typename... T>
typename std::enable_if<all_same<typename std::decay<T>::type...>::value, void>::type
func(T&&...)
{ }
```

Alternatively, if you have a general purpose trait for testing the logical conjunction you can do it using `std::is_same` instead of writing your own `all_same`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<and_<is_same<T, Ts>...>::value, void>::type
func(T&&, Ts&&...)
{ }
```

Because this requires at least one argument you'd also need another overload to support the zero-argument case:

```
void func() { }
```

The `and_` helper can be defined like so:

```
template<typename...>
  struct and_;

template<>
  struct and_<>
  : public std::true_type
  { };

template<typename B1>
  struct and_<B1>
  : public B1
  { };

template<typename B1, typename B2>
  struct and_<B1, B2>
  : public std::conditional<B1::value, B2, B1>::type
  { };

template<typename B1, typename B2, typename B3, typename... Bn>
  struct and_<B1, B2, B3, Bn...>
  : public std::conditional<B1::value, and_<B2, B3, Bn...>, B1>::type
  { };
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not 100% the same as the putative `func(Foo... foos)`, because if `Foo` has a non-explicit constructor, `func({x, y, z})` won't work -- the compiler can't infer the type of `{x, y, z}` unless that type is specified in the signature of `func`.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can do this by specifying a concrete type when chewing your arguments out of the argument pack. Something like:

```
class MyClass{};
class MyOtherClass{};

void func()
{
    // do something
}

template< typename... Arguments >
void func( MyClass arg, Arguments ... args )
{
    // do something with arg
    func( args... );
    // do something more with arg
}


void main()
{
    MyClass a, b, c;
    MyOtherClass d;
    int i;
    float f;

    func( a, b, c );    // compiles fine
    func( i, f, d );    // cannot convert
}
```

In the generic case `void func( MyClass arg, Arguments ... args )` would become `void func( arg, Arguments ... args )` with a template type T.

Answer (score 11):

@Skeen
How about this?

```
template <typename T>
void func_1(std::initializer_list<T>&& a) {
    // do something
} 

template <typename... T>
void func(T&&... a) {
    func_1({std::forward<T>(a)...});
} 

int main() {
    func(1, 2, 3);
    // func(1, 2, 3, 4.0); // OK doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: @Barry have you tried? I did at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm
both literal int and int& are decayed on function call.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use brace-based `initializer_list`/`vector` and want to keep the arguments separate in form of argument pack, then below solution checks it at compile time using recursive `static_assert`s:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Error>
struct is_same : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename... Checking>
struct is_same<T, T, Checking...> : is_same<T, Checking...> {}; 

template<typename T>
struct is_same<T,T> : std::true_type {};

template<typename... LeftMost>
void func (LeftMost&&... args)
{
  static_assert(is_same<typename std::decay<LeftMost>::type...>::value, 
                "All types are not same as 'LeftMost'");
  // ...
}

int main ()
{
  int var = 2;
  func(1,var,3,4,5);  // ok
  func(1,2,3,4.0,5); // error due to `static_assert` failure
}
```

Actually this solution would check all the arguments with respect to the first argument. Suppose it was `double` then everything would be checked against `double`.

Comment: Using a forwarding reference (`LeftMost&&`) means that the static assertion will fail if you call the function with a mix of lvalues and rvalues, e.g. `int i=0; func(i, 1);` so it would be better to check `is_same<typename std::decay<LeftMost>::type...>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because I don't think I saw this solution, you could write a specific function for every type (in your case, just `int`) then a forwarding function taking variadic argument types.

Write each specific case:

then for each specific case:

```
// only int in your case
void func(int i){
    std::cout << "int i = " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Then your forwarding function like this:

```
template<typename Arg0, typename Arg1 typename ... Args>
void func(Arg0 &&arg0, Arg1 &&arg1, Args &&... args){
    func(std::forward<Arg0>(arg0));
    func(std::forward<Arg1>(arg1), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This is good because it is expandable for when you want to accept maybe another type too.

Used like this:

```
int main(){
    func(1, 2, 3, 4); // works fine
    func(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f); // compile error, no func(float)
}
```