# How can I map a C++ parameter pack into a sequence of std::pair objects?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a variadic template function `foo()`:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args &&... args);
```

This function is intended to be invoked with all arguments of `size_t`. I can enforce that using [some metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017543/c11-variable-number-of-arguments-same-specific-type). I need to take the resulting list of arguments two at a time and put them into a container of `std::pair<size_t, size_t>`. Conceptually, something like:

```
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t> > = { 
    std::make_pair(args[0], args[1]), 
    std::make_pair(args[2], args[3]), ...
};
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I know that by pack expansion, I could put the arguments into a flat container, but is there a way to group them two by two into `std::pair` objects at the same time?

Comment: "*Is there a straightforward way to do this?*" No.

Comment: I guess, one could make a recursive inserter which would consume two arguments, and push_back them as pairs into vector, with two stop-case specializations.

Comment: Any chance you could forward to an internal helper function that has an additional `std::index_sequence<I...>` parameter?

Comment: @KerrekSB: That would be feasible, but I'm still getting used to working with C++11 features, so I'm not sure how it would work. `std::index_sequence<>` is C++14-only as well, isn't it? Not a showstopper, but I would want to be aware of it.

Comment: @JasonR: You can define any template equivalent to `index_sequence` yourself trivially.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indexing into packs isn't really doable (yet?), but indexing into tuples is. Just stick everything into a tuple first, and then pull everything back out as you go. Since everything's a `size_t`, we can just copy:

```
template <size_t... Is, class Tuple>
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> 
foo_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple tuple) {
    return std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t> >{ 
        std::make_pair(std::get<2*Is>(tuple), std::get<2*Is+1>(tuple))...
    };
}

template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args)
{
    auto vs = foo_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)/2>{},
        std::make_tuple(args...));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe even `std::forward_as_tuple`?

Comment: @KerrekSB They're all `size_t`s. Pretty sure the compiler will elide the `tuple` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are allowed to refactor your logic into an internal helper function:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void foo(Args &&... args)
{
    foo_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) / 2>(),
             std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Now we can operate on the argument pack index by index:

```
template <std::size_t ...I, typename ...Args>
void foo_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>, Args &&... args)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>> v =
        { GetPair(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>(), args...)... };
}
```

It remains to implement the pair extractor:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename ...Tail>
std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> GetPair(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>,
                                            A a, B b, Tail ... tail)
{
    return { a, b };
}

template <std::size_t I, typename A, typename B, typename ...Tail>
std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> GetPair(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>,
                                            A a, B b, Tail ... tail)
{
    return GetPair<I - 1>(tail...);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I accepted Barry's answer since it was a bit more brief, but this looks like a good solution as well.

Comment: @JasonR: Yes, `std::get` is effectively for tuples what my `GetPair` is for raw packs. Tuples are very powerful for this sort of generic code.

Answer (score 2):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{
    std::initializer_list<std::size_t> nbs = {static_cast<std::size_t>(args)...};
    const auto pair_view =
        ranges::view::zip(nbs | ranges::view::stride(2),
                          nbs | ranges::view::drop(1) |  ranges::view::stride(2));

    // And possibly
    std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>> pairs = pair_view;
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ffd3935d79b791e)

Comment: ranges are beautiful :)

Comment: The last line could be nicened up as: auto pairs = pair_view | transform({return std::make_pair(...);}) | ranges::to_vector;

Comment: I like this a lot. I was originally thinking along these lines, but I'll have to wait until ranges get into the standard!

Answer (score 1):

Someone (*cough* @Barry *cough*) said that indexing into packs isn't possible.

This is C++.  Impossible means we just haven't written it yet.

```
template<std::size_t I> struct index_t:std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {
  using std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>::integral_constant;
  template<std::size_t J>
  constexpr index_t<I+J> operator+( index_t<J> ) const { return {}; }
  template<std::size_t J>
  constexpr index_t<I-J> operator-( index_t<J> ) const { return {}; }
  template<std::size_t J>
  constexpr index_t<I*J> operator*( index_t<J> ) const { return {}; }
  template<std::size_t J>
  constexpr index_t<I/J> operator/( index_t<J> ) const { return {}; }
};
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index{};

template<std::size_t B>
constexpr index_t<1> exponent( index_t<B>, index_t<0> ) { return {}; }

template<std::size_t B, std::size_t E>
constexpr auto exponent( index_t<B>, index_t<E> ) {
  return index<B> * exponent( index<B>, index<E-1> );
}
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr index_t<0> from_base(index_t<N>) { return {}; }
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t c>
constexpr index_t<c-'0'> from_base(index_t<N>, index_t<c>) { return {}; }
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t c0, std::size_t...cs>
constexpr auto from_base(index_t<N>, index_t<c0>, index_t<cs>...) {
  return 
    from_base(index<N>, index<c0>) * exponent(index<N>, index<sizeof...(cs)>)
    + from_base(index<N>, index<cs>...)
  ;
}

template<char...cs>
constexpr auto operator""_idx(){
  return from_base(index<10>, index<cs>...);
}

auto nth = [](auto index_in){
  return [](auto&&...elems)->decltype(auto){
    using std::get;
    constexpr auto I= index<decltype(index_in){}>;
    return get<I>(std::forward_as_tuple(decltype(elems)(elems)...));
  };
};
```

Now we get:

```
using pair_vec = std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>>;
template <typename... Args>
pair_vec foo(Args &&... args) {
  return
    index_over< sizeof...(args)/2 >()
    ([&](auto...Is)->pair_vec{
      return {
        {
          nth( Is*2_idx )( decltype(args)(args)... ),
          nth( Is*2_idx+1_idx )( decltype(args)(args)... )
        }...
      };
    });
}
```

where we "directly" index into our parameter packs using compile time constant indexes.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dae52bb8280e6f3).

Comment: Very impressive. I'm a few years behind the modern C++ curve, so I'm a long way from being able to dream up a solution like this from scratch. Nice demonstration.