# What would be equal of Java function with any number of parameters in C++?

Tags: c++

What would be equal of Java function with any number of parameters in C++?

```
void anyNumberOfParamas(String... strings) {
    for (String str : strings) {
        // do something with string
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579719/variable-number-of-parameters-in-function-in-c possible duplicate. ... exists in c, too.

Comment: [Variadic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic), and since C++11 [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), more general and powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices: a *variadic template* or a function taking `std::initializer_list`.

---

The first one looks like this:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void anyNumberOfParams(const Ts&... xs)
{
    (something(xs), ...);
}
```

With this approach, you get a different instantiation of `anyNumberOfParams` each you time you call it with different types. The "iteration" is done at compile-time.

You also need to constrain `Ts...` properly if you want to allow this function to only accept `std::string`.

---

The second one looks like this:

```
void anyNumberOfParams(std::initializer_list<std::string> xs)
{
    for(const auto& x : xs) something(x);
}
```

[`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is basically syntactic sugar over a `const` array of elements. In this case, the iteration is done at run-time and there is only a single instantiation of `anyNumberOfParams`.

Unfortunately, `std::initializer_list` has quirks you should be aware of (e.g. cannot move elements from it).

Comment: Is there a benefit to taking a `std::initializer_list` by const reference? (Genuine question).

Comment: Don't forget the `va_args` stuff too. Old-fashioned yes, but tried and tested. Not mentioning them any more is like not being allowed to talk about your ex-girlfriends.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Why not ask the community?

Comment: @Bathsheba - That's plan B.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Ping me if you do. I'll up it.

Comment: @StoryTeller initializer_list should probably not be taken by const reference, since it's always created by value. It's basically `struct { T const* data; std::size_t size; };`. If you look at any standard library functions or constructors that take an initializer_list, they do so by value

Comment: @Galik: then you have dynamic allocation. Use variadic templates instead.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I  just realized it wouldn't work anyway because you would need to pass by `const&`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo what about if I need to access two or more string at the same time, in Java: `strings[0]` `strings[1]` (access first two strings)

Comment: @user924: you can do it in many ways. In the variadic template case, you can use metaprogramming to extract the  nth element from a pack.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo as I see the second solution won't work for me (in my case, for my task), __initializer_list doesn't provide subscripting.__

Comment: Where is the third choice of variadic functions? They are fine for their uses.