# How to get the pointer to an object from a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-pack

I'm having trouble with getting 2 different objects of the same type to have pointers to different objects using a parameter pack. Here is Controller.h:

```
using expand_type = int[];

template<typename... Ts> class Controller {
public:
    Controller(int i, string s, Ts... args): id(i), name(s) {
        expand_type{ (add_component(&args), 0)... };

    }
    void add_component(Test2* a) {
        device_.push_back(a);
    }
    void print() {
        cout<<name<<":"<<endl;
        cout<<"================="<<endl;
        for (vector<Test2*>::size_type i = 0; i < device_.size(); ++i) {
            cout<<device_[i]->print()<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"================="<<endl;
    }
private:
    vector<Test2*> device_;
    int id;
    string name;
};
```

and here is my Test2.h:

```
class Test2 {
public:
    Test2(): x(0) {}
    Test2(int a): x(a) {}
    int print() const {
        return x;
    }
private:
    int x;
};
```

My problem is when I make two seperate Controller objects, they share their Test2 objects in their respective vectors. Here is my main:

```
int main() {
    Test2 b(69);
    Test2 c(666);
    Test2 d(943754);
    Controller<Test2, Test2, Test2, Test2> x(2, string("Peter"), 70, b, c, d);
    Controller<> y(2, string("Pietje"));
    Controller<Test2, Test2, Test2, Test2> z(3, string("Jan"), 909, 808, 1, 2);

    x.print();
    y.print();
    z.print();

    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

then the output is:

```
Peter:
=================
0
808
1
2
=================
Pietje:
=================
=================
Jan:
=================
0
808
1
2
=================
hello
```

I want the different objects of Controller to have different pointers to different Test2 objects, and I'v3 no clue how.

Also, as a side problem; my first pointer always becomes 0, unless it's the only object in the vector.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The first problem is that you are adding pointers to local variables, which go out of scope after the constructor. Hence, accessing these is undefined behavior. Why do you have a variadic template in the first place if all you can process are `Test2` objects? Try to explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: How else would you make sure you can pass any number of arguments to the object constructor? I'm new to this so I really don't know. About the local variables, aren't I putting these pointers into the vector, which stores them?

Comment: I am trying to make it so you can make a Controller object with any number of Test2 objects, which are stored into the Test2* vector.

Comment: Passing an initializer list or a vector (possible as an rvalue reference) seem to be the better thing to do. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579719/variable-number-of-parameters-in-function-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Side-stepping the funky behavior, your main problem here is ownership: Does `Controller` own the devices, and if not who? Let's say the controller doesn't own the devices. Then stuff like this will cause problems

```cpp
Controller<...> z(3, string("Jan"), 909, 808, 1, 2);
                                    ^^^ temporary object's lifetime ends immediately
                                        it won't have a valid address to point to
```

Your experience will be much better once you plan it out. Let's say `Controller` owns the devices: just use a vector of `Test2` and you're set.

Next issue is the variadic template. It looks like the `device_`s are all the same type, and the only use for the variadic template is to have a variable number of constructor arguments. If so, just use a variadic template for the constructor, and make the class a plain ol' simple type:

```cpp
class Controller {
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    Controller(int i, string s, Ts&&... args): id(i), name(s), device_ { std::forward<Ts>(args)... } { }
    // ...
};
```

Put it all together, and everything works as expected:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test2 {
public:
    Test2(): x(0) {}
    Test2(int a): x(a) {}
    int print() const {
        return x;
    }
private:
    int x;
};

class Controller {
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    Controller(int i, string s, Ts&&... args): id(i), name(s), device_ { std::forward<Ts>(args)... } { }

    void print() {
        cout<<name<<":"<<endl;
        cout<<"================="<<endl;
        for (auto& device : device_) {
            cout<<device.print()<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"================="<<endl;
    }
private:
    vector<Test2> device_;
    int id;
    string name;
};

int main() {
    Test2 b(69);
    Test2 c(666);
    Test2 d(943754);
    Controller x(2, string("Peter"), 70, b, c, d);
    Controller y(2, string("Pietje"));
    Controller z(3, string("Jan"), 909, 808, 1, 2);

    x.print();
    y.print();
    z.print();

    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
Peter:
=================
70
69
666
943754
=================
Pietje:
=================
=================
Jan:
=================
909
808
1
2
=================
hello
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bLjgaf

---

UPDATE:
Per your request, let's say `Controller` only stores raw pointers and doesn't own the `Test2` devices. First, you have to pass *references* to the contructor so the object's address is accessible:

```cpp
class Controller {
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    Controller(int i, string s, Ts&... args): id(i), name(s), device_ { &args... } { }
    // ...
};
```

Then you have to make sure *every* object you pass it *outlives* the controller:

```cpp
Test2 b(69);
Test2 c(666);
Test2 d(943754);
Controller x(2, string("Peter"), b, c, d); // this is fine
Controller y(2, string("Pietje"));         // this is fine
Controller z(3, string("Jan"), 909, 808, 1, 2); // uh oh!
```

So far, we've only ever talked about stack-allocated `Test2` objects. You can also dynamically allocate an object and get a pointer to it. This pointer only has a single owner, and you can *transfer* ownership with `std::move`:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Test2> = std::make_unique<Test2>(42);
```

You can also create a pointer with *shared* ownership. You can copy this pointer, and the last surviving pointer will clean up the object:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Test2> = std::make_shared<Test2>(42);
```

BUT, I can't recommend this if you're trying to learn about memory models. A lot of times people use it as a way of avoiding thinking about memory models. If everything has a clear owner, it makes your life much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but the point of the vector is to have Test2 pointers in them, so how would you do it then? The devices are owned by no-one, or that's the idea anyway. Also, what does `Ts&&` and `std::forward<Ts>(args)...` mean?

Comment: Why is the point to have a vector of pointers? I mean, you can, but the pointers have to point to an object. And if those objects come from elsewhere, they have to outlive `Controller`, or else the pointers will become invalid. So, you can have a bunch of Test2's outside the struct and pass those in, you just have to have a mental model of what those objects' lifetimes are. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: `Ts&&` and `std::forward` is a pattern called perfect forwarding. It avoids unnecessary copying if all you're doing is passing the arguments of a function or constructor to another function or constructor instead of using them: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c .

Comment: Yeah, I do have a model. The question is how do you get different pointers to different objects of the same class into different vectors of different objects of the same class.

Comment: Or should i just make it so Controller owns the Test2's? It would be easier, but it isn't really what I had planned.

Comment: What do you mean by "different vectors of different objects of  the same class". Are there multiple controllers and a single pool of devices?

Comment: It's pretty normal to just have a context object that owns all your controllers and devices. That way all the objects stay alive (and their pointers stay valid) until the context is destroyed. Then you can store raw pointers for references without worrying

Comment: Each Controller object has a vector<Test2*>, which needs to store pointers to different Test2 objects. There are let's say 5 Controllers and 50 Test2's. Each Controller would then have 10 Test2's for example.  The current problem is that each Controller object would save the last 10 pointers to Test2 objects, which you can see in my output in the original question.