# C: Pass array in place of variable argument list

Tags: c, exec, variadic-functions

I am writing a simple shell in C. It is actually coming along quite well with i/o redirection and such. One thing that I'd like to add is a way to switch between versions of the exec* functions. Right now I'm sticking to execlp(), execvp(), and execve().

I have all the arguments I want to pass in an array called argv. It is a null terminated array of null terminated strings, so it works fine with execv*, but I can't think of how to get it to work with execlp().

This is what I have now:

```
if     (strcmp(exec_opt, "vp") == 0)
  error = execvp(argv[0], argv);          /* Execute vp */
else if(strcmp(exec_opt, "lp") == 0)
  error = execlp(argv[0], "", argv);      /* Execute lp */
else if(strcmp(exec_opt, "ve") == 0)
  error = execve(argv[0], argv, environ); /* Execute ve */
else
{
  // throw errors about exec_opt
}

if(error != 0)
{
  // do something about it
}
```

In this configuration the compiler doesn't baff at the syntax, but it also doesn't work.
I've also tried

```
 error = execlp(argv[0], (char*) argv);  /* As a single string */
 char* argv1 = argv[1];                  /* don't pass command itself */
 error = execlp(argv[0], argv1);
```

Which do various odd but ultimately incorrect things. Is there a way for me to turn my array into a variable argument list? passing it directly (which makes the most type-sense, since variable argument lists are `char* argv[]`) yields a compiler error about casting incompatible pointers.

Comment: I don't see the point in trying to use the execl* functions.  They are only there to make it easier to call the functions when you don't have all the parameters in an array, but you do.

Comment: @VaughnCato I realize this, but the point of selecting these functions at runtime is to illustrate how they vary from function to function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use `execlp()` with the array.  To use `execlp()`, you have to write out:

```
execlp(array[0], array[0], (char *)0);
execlp(array[0], array[0], array[1], (char *)0);
execlp(array[0], array[0], array[1], array[2], (char *)0);
execlp(array[0], array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], (char *)0);
...
```

for each alternative number of arguments.  This is why [`execvp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) was added to the repertoire (it wasn't part of [7th Edition UNIX™](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/index.html) in 1978, but was part of [SUS v2](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/) in 1997).  Now you just need `execvpe()`, which does not exist AFAIK (and I don't know why it isn't provided, either).

---

### 7<sup>th</sup> Edition UNIX did have `excevp()`

Dave said:

> The 7th Edition manual does list `execvp`.

And ... it does, partially.  I think we have an erratum to report since the manual actually contains:

> #### NAME
>
> execl, execv, execle, execve, execlp, execvp, exec, exece, environ – execute a file
>
> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> execl(name, arg0, arg1, ..., argn, 0)
> char *name, *arg0, *arg1, ..., *argn;
> execv(name, argv)
> char *name, *argv[ ];
> execle(name, arg0, arg1, ..., argn, 0, envp)
> char *name, *arg0, *arg1, ..., *argn, *envp[ ];
> execve(name, argv, envp);
> char *name, *argv[ ], *envp[ ];
> extern char **environ;
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION

So, `execvp()` is listed in the NAME section, but there is no synopsis for `execvp()` (which is what I looked at to come to the conclusion it was missing).  There is a reference to `execvp()` on the next page:

> *Execlp* and *execvp* are called with the same arguments as *execl* and *execv*, but duplicate the shell’s actions in searching for an executable file in a list of directories. The directory list is obtained from the environment.

So, I excuse myself because I scanned the SYNOPSIS and `execvp()` was omitted from the synopsis.  But actually, the system call was present in 7th Edition Unix.  I don't think anyone is about to re-release the manuals with the omission fixed.

My print copy (yes, I *do* have printed properly bound versions of both Volume 1 (ISBN 0-03-061742-1) and Volume 2 (ISBN 0-03-061743-X) of the manual from way back then; I obtained them circa 1989) has the same omission in the SYNOPSIS section.

Comment: You could build `execvpe()` fairly easily by forking, fixing up the environment the way you want it, and then calling `execvp()`

Comment: @Huckle: yes - I suppose so.  And because the child is guaranteed single-threaded, there's no multi-threading problem unless you did something weird like place parts of the environment in shared memory and something modifies it before the child gets to `execve()`.

Comment: @Huckle why fork? No-one in the `exec` family forks.

Comment: @Dave: good point; I was assuming 'after the fork', rather than reading what was said.  Nevertheless, Huckle's point that `execvpe()` is not all that hard to code is basically correct.  Something like: `int execvpe(const char *cmd, char *const* argv, char *const* envp) { environ = envp; return execvp(cmd, argv); }`, which is not dramatically difficult.  I stand by 'it would (occasionally) be nice if it was there already'; but it isn't a critical omission (unlike `execvp()` from 7th Edition Unix).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler for what it's worth, the [7th edition manual](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/bswv7.html) does list `execvp`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [avcall](http://www.haible.de/bruno/documentation/ffcall/avcall/avcall.html).  I haven't used it myself, I just found an interesting mention of it here: [Passing parameters dynamically to variadic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721655/passing-parameters-dynamically-to-variadic-functions)

Comment: This seems interesting, but it is a requirement to stick strictly to C and POSIX functions only for portability purposes. I guess I could do something similar by building a space-delimited string from the array, but I figured there might be a better way.

Comment: That's interesting - thanks for the x-ref.  I'm not sure it's a good solution to the problem compared with abandoning `execlp()` and simply using `execvp()`.