# Passing all elements of an array to a function with variable parameters (...)

Tags: c, parameters, optional-parameters

I need to pass a variable number of parameters to a c-function that allows a variable number of parameters.

```
function a(int n , ...) {...} //*n* number of parameters

int b[XXX]; //XXX is more or less run-time dynamic.
//Filsignals.https://github.com/libpd/libpd/blob/master/pure-data/src/d_ugen.cl b with things.
a(n, b[0], b[1] ... b[XXX])
```

How to write this without naming each single element of b?

One thing: I cannot change the implementation of `a()` and it uses the `va_list` to access "...".
Thus, I cannot pass `a(n, b)` as "b" would only be handled as *one* parameter only, but it contains more.

Just more details: a() is actually the puredata `dsp_add()` function (defined in [`d_ugen.c`](https://github.com/libpd/libpd/blob/master/pure-data/src/d_ugen.c)) that is uses the passed pointers to set up incoming and outgoing.

### One option

I just found that I can avoid this problem by using [`dsp_addv()`](https://github.com/libpd/libpd/blob/master/pure-data/src/d_ugen.c#L318), which is an array version of the variadic `dsp_add()` function.

However, this does not answer my question...

Comment: pass an array as a paramter void func(a);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters dynamically to variadic functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721655/passing-parameters-dynamically-to-variadic-functions)

Comment: It might help to know what `a` does. For example, if it just treats all arguments separately, you could write a wrapper loop. If it is a reduction function that calculates a single value from the input, there may be no good way to do what you want.

Comment: is it possible using Macro?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do that, unless you use some ugly macro magic.

Comment: @2501 I do not like magic ;) I will go with dsp_addv() and it will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already found an answer to your problem. I think using the array variant of the function is the way to go. (The comment on the `dsp_addv` function is telling.)

> However, this does not answer my question...

Depending on the nature of the variadic function, you can write a wrapper function that calls the variadic function. This will not work in all cases, but for some frequent cases. (Variadic functions themselves are rather restricted in their use. Somewhere, I've read a claim that they exist only to implement `printf`.)

#### Iteration

Something is done to each variadic argument: It is printed, for example, or it is added to a list. In that case you can just call the function for each argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void varg_print(const char *str, ...)
{
    va_list va;

    va_start(va, str);
    while (str) {
        puts(str);
        str = va_arg(va, const char *);
    }
    va_end(va);
}

void arr_print(const char **str)
{    
    while (*str) varg_print(*str++, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    const char *fruit[]) = {"apple", "pear", "banana", NULL};
    arr_print(fruit);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Reduction

All arguments are reduced to a single value, for example their sum or their max values. Here you can treat sub-arrays until you get what you want. The example below forwards an array to a summation function at most four elements at a time and overwrites the lower regions of the array with the result until there is only a single value left.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

double varg_sum(int n, ...)
{
    double s = 0.0;
    va_list va;

    va_start(va, n);
    while (n--) s += va_arg(va, double);
    va_end(va);

    return s;
}

double arr_sum(int n, double *x)
{
    double r[n];

    if (n <= 0) return 0.0;

    memcpy(r, x, n * sizeof(*x));

    while (n > 1) {
        double *p = r;
        int m = 0;

        while (n) {
            switch (n) {
            case 1:     r[m++] = varg_sum(1, p[0]);
                        n -= 1;
                        p += 1;
                        break;

            case 2:     r[m++] = varg_sum(2, p[0], p[1]);
                        n -= 2;
                        p += 2;
                        break;

            case 3:     r[m++] = varg_sum(3, p[0], p[1], p[2]);
                        n -= 3;
                        p += 3;
                        break;

            default:    r[m++] = varg_sum(4, p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);
                        n -= 4;
                        p += 4;
                        break;
            }
        }

        n = m;   
    }

    return r[0];
}

int main()
{
    double x[100];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) x[i] = i + 1.0;
    printf("%g\n", arr_sum(100, x));   

    return 0;
}
```

The code makes a copy of the array so that the original array isn't destroyed. You can increase the chunk size in order to treat bigger arrays more effectively, but variadic functions aren't designed for long variadic lists anyway, so four seems okay.

Answer (score 0):

Is `a()` something that can be modified or part of the api of something else?

If you can change it, instead of using a variadic function, I'd define the function as:

```
function a(int n, int* params)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

and just pass the array into it.

If it isn't an option, I'd look into the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721655/passing-parameters-dynamically-to-variadic-functions?lq=1) and implement it into a wrapper function, so you can just pass your array to that, keeping your code as simple as possible.