# Passing a vararg list to a sub-function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

**EDIT:** I am afraid I have not been clear.

What I wanted is to pass a (portion or all) of a vararg list to a sub-function without having to pass all the vararg parameters.

I did some research (trial & error) and found the solution, which I post as an answer.

I have deleted the original question because it was unclear. Thanks for your comments, which helped me to find the errors in my thoughts.

Comment: Why can't you simply pass `argv[2]` as a pointer to sum? You'd have to use `va_start`, `va_arg` etc. otherwise which is more of a hassle.

Comment: I think it's not even possible to pass them as varargs. Just pass the pointer.

Comment: It's not standarized C atleast, it would require some assembly to manually push the desired parameters, and invoke the variadic function correctly. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721655/passing-parameters-dynamically-to-variadic-functions/1721684#1721684) answer for details.

Comment: You don't have variadic input to `main`, so how would you pass them as variadic? C is not Python where you can pack/unpack lists as arguments. You seem to be confusing an array of arbitrary size (open array) and variadic arguments.

Comment: @Linus: This would indeed be very implementation-specific and requires to study the PCS/ABI of the target platform. However, this is nonsense here, as the arguments are already in an array.

Comment: Why do you thing `argv` is located on the stack? There is no requirement (and no proof). Indeed, C does not even require a stack.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the last paragraph, can you rephrase it or show a code example of what you mean?

Comment: @m-m (and others), I rephrased my question and with trial & error came up with a solution. It was more simple than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a main test function. It calls a function that can take a variable number of arguments. That funtion in turn calls a sub-function to do the work. It gets passed the argument list, but not by passing the parameters but by passing the address of the vararg list. It then processes this list:

```
void va_test1(int n,...);
void va_test2(int n, va_list argptr);

int va_main(void)
{
    va_test1(5, 1,2,3,4,5);
    return(1);
}
void va_test1(int n,...)
{
    va_list argptr;

    va_start (argptr, n);
    va_test2 (n, argptr);
    va_end (argptr);
}
void va_test2(int n, va_list argptr)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\n", va_arg( argptr, int ));
}
```

Comment: Your `va_test2`'s second parameter should just be `va_list argptr`. It is not guaranteed that you can assign `void *` to `va_list` or vice versa. Also, you should `va_end` when you're done.

Comment: @newacct, thanks for your comments. I have updated the solution. `va_end` seems not necessary as it only resets the `argptr`.