# Calling functions with different arg count

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm decompiling a very old game, and my goal is to restore 100% native code.  As such, I would need to preserve the existing architecture as much as possible (e.g. just using `std::function` isn't really helpful).

I have a collection of **static** functions with different number of parameters. They are stored in structure like this:

```
struct ScriptFunction 
{
    const wchar_t* m_name;
    void* m_func;  // ptr to specific function 
    void* m_returnType;
    int m_argCount;
};
```

And are populated like this:

```
ScriptFunction s_functions[206] = {
    {L"AddMoveAroundDesire", &ScriptFunctions::AddMoveAroundDesire, &CScriptType::s_void, 2},
    {L"AddDoNothingDesire", &ScriptFunctions::AddDoNothingDesire, &CScriptType::s_void, 2},
    {L"AddAttackDesire", &ScriptFunctions::AddAttackDesire, &CScriptType::s_void, 3},
    {L"AddAttackDesireEx", &ScriptFunctions::AddAttackDesireEx, &CScriptType::s_void, 4},
    {L"AddGetItemDesire", &ScriptFunctions::AddGetItemDesire, &CScriptType::s_void, 2},
 ...
```

So, how can I invoke **ScriptFunction::m_func** with given **m_argCount** and **void****  arguments? I have to push parameters somehow on stack and invoke func-call, but I have no idea.

Some asm code? va_list? But how to fill it in run-time?

**UPD:** Invoker looks like this

```
void CScriptAccessible::InvokeInternal(ScriptFunction* scriptFunc, void** args)
{
    // here I have to push params from **args** to stack 
    // and somehow call ScriptFunction::m_func
    // In assembly I could see pushes to stack in a loop (driven by 
    // ScriptFunction::m_argCount). But I'm wondering, whether it's 
    // possible to do in C++ (push args on stack and call function by just address)
}
```

Comment: I removed the unneeded tag for you. If you can explain, why it is helpful feel free to re-add it, together with the explanation, and accept my apology.

Comment: How do you get the arguments? And how do you want to pass them?

Comment: Are the `ScriptFunctions` functions (`Scriptfunctions::AddMoveAroundDesire`, etc) static or non-static?     How does each one work with a supplied `ScriptFunction`?    Those questions are rather fundamental in picking options to invoke/call them, given only a member named `m_func` that is a `void *` and a set of `void **` arguments.

Comment: ScriptFunctions::* are static (free). Changed in description. The only single usage is inside `CScriptAccessible::InvokeInternal`. In assembly I could see pushes to stack in a loop (driven by `ScriptFunction::m_argCount`). But I'm wondering, whether it's possible to do in C++ (push args on stack and call function by just address)

Comment: No it is not possible to do it in C++ in general, you either do it with `std::function` or make it platform specific ie using assembly.

Comment: If all functions take pointers as arguments and return void and the max number of arguments is known then I think the following might work: cast `m_func` to pointer to a variadic function and then use a switch to call it with the right number of arguments.

Comment: @MikhailVasilyev yes, it would be a workaround, to use `switch` and `cast`, depending on `ScriptFunction::m_argCount`. But in original code there is no switch, only loop with `push`es

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1721684/4432988).

Comment: What things are and aren't you willing to change? The declarations of the called functions? The `ScriptFunction` type? The `s_functions` array? Is it okay if one or more need to be "duplicated" with two different types where one just uses the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the language, there is only the `switch`/cast solution.  That lets the compiler generate the correct calling convention: *e.g.*, on x86-64 Linux, the first several arguments are passed in predefined registers.  (The optimizer might merge the different paths into jumps into a sort of unrolled loop of the kind you’re expecting.)  Remember also that in C/C++ alone, there is no “stack” at all.

Incidentally, using `void*` for functions is not guaranteed either (since it can point to any *object* but they are not objects), although it usually works (and POSIX requires it for `dlsym`).

Comment: I ended up with `switch/case/cast-to-proper-func-prototype` solution. I think, in original code they used asm, since it's quite clear from the binary code.